# A subset of the set of numbers of seven non zero digits

Tags: combinatorics

Someone visits me knowing that I'm indisposed for now. Courteously, brings me a problem without imagining it is on my “bête noir”, Combinatorics.

I post it with its solution, **151200**, I think am unable to find and with the hope that this might interest someone.

**How many numbers of seven non zero digits are there such that 2 and 4 are never in consecutive position?**

Comment: Just draw the tree diagram :) It should be immediate from that

Comment: @b00nheT although that will work, it is tedious and is clearly not the intended solution.  How would making a tree diagram work in the case that we were asking for a number 100 digits long?

Comment: I would recommend approaching via recurrence relations.  If $a_n$ is the number of $n$-length strings of nonzero digits which have no substring "$24$" and no substring "$42$", try to relate that to $a_{n-1},a_{n-2},\dots$

Comment: Python script gives $4159927$.

Comment: `print sum(['0' not in str(n) and '24' not in str(n) and '42' not in str(n) for n in range(1000000,10000000)])` in case anyone was wondering...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following JMoravitz's suggestion, a solution using a recurrence relation: Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be the number of admissible strings with $n$ non-zero digits that do and don't, respectively, end in $2$ or $4$. Then

\begin{align}
a_{n+1}=\hphantom{1}a_n+2b_n\;,\\
b_{n+1}=7a_n+7b_n\;,
\end{align}

or

$$
\pmatrix{a\\b}_{n+1}=\pmatrix{1&2\\7&7}\pmatrix{a\\b}_n\;.
$$

Since the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of this matrix aren't nice and you only want $a_7+b_7$, the easiest way to proceed seems to be to directly calculate $a_n$ and $b_n$ up to $n=7$:

\begin{array}{c|cc}
n&a_n&b_n\\\hline
1&2&7\\
2&16&63\\
3&142&553\\
4&1248&4865\\
5&10978&42791\\
6&96560&376383\\
7&849326&3310601
\end{array}

The result is $a_7+b_7=4159927$, in agreement with barak manos's Python script and in disagreement with the solution you proposed.

Perhaps there was a misunderstanding about the question somewhere along the way?

Comment: I am unable, dear friend, to say something pertinent about your last question. However, see, please, at my comment for André.

Comment: In the book "Introductory Combinatorics" by R.A. Brualdy (North Holland, 1977, page 30) the answer to a similar problem it could be another mistake. Maybe not because the source of this has itself a mistake. Thanks you. Regards.